# Add class property to file using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, reflection, preg-replace

How can I add a property to a class (or any string in that matter) using regular expressions?

I want to have something like:

```
<?php

class Foo extends Sth
{
    protected $bar;
}
```

into:

```
<?php

class Foo extends Sth
{
    protected $newProperty;
    protected $bar;
}
```

The entry point for pattern should be keyword `class` and first `{`.

What is the best way of doing that? Maybe there is a better way than regular expressions? The classes affected will be of course much more complicated so I don't think that reflections are answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how complex the other classes can be, but that regex works on the sample you have:

```
/class[^\r\n]+\R\{(\s*)(?=.*?\})/s
```

And replacing with:

```
$0protected $newProperty;$1
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV9uF1)